# Is it possible to call a class defined in another file from a JNI function?

Tags: android, c++

In a JNI class, I want to use a class defined in another file. Let's say my JNI function is:

```
#include "myClass.h"

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_vd63_utilitaires_panorama_TraitementVolcans_initialiseVolcansJNI(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                                         jobject instance) {
    myClass r = myClass();
}
```

The "myClass.h" file looks like this :

```
class myClass{
    public: int x,y;

    public: myClass();

    public: myClass(int,int);

    public: ~myClass();
}
```

And my "myClass.cpp" file :

```
#include "myClass.h"

myClass::myClass(): x(0), y(0) {}

myClass::myClass(int x,int y) : x(x),y(y) {}

myClass::~myClass(){
```

In the editor, I have no error and no warning, but when I try to make the project, it fails with the following error :  CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. myClass.

Does anyone know how I can solve my problem?

My CMakeLists.txt file is :

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

```
add_library( 
    native-lib

    SHARED

    native-lib.cpp)

find_library(
          log-lib

          log )

find_library(
    libjnigraphics-lib

    jnigraphics )

target_link_libraries(
    native-lib

    ${log-lib})

target_link_libraries(
    native-lib

    ${libjnigraphics-lib} )
```

Comment: Why did you write `Point::myClass`? The class is named `myClass`, not `Point`.

Comment: Also, instead of `myClass r = myClass();` you can just write `myClass r;`

Comment: As for the error message in your question, you should probably show what your CMakeLists.txt looks like.

Comment: Yes, `Point::myClass`was a cut and pastre error. My CmakeLists.txt file is now added to my question.

Comment: By the looks of your CMakeLists.txt, you're never compiling myClass.cpp.

Comment: But how can I do that?

Comment: Problem solved : source and include files declared in a `set` block and library added with these two blocks.